# make Grid disabled when I hover on an other Grid in a universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to ask,if this is possible,in my case I have 2 columns and 2 rows,every part contains a Grid like this:

```
 <Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
      </Grid>

       <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
      </Grid>

      <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
      </Grid>

       <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
      </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I want when I hover on one Grid,the other Grids and their components will be disabled,I have search for a property like "IsEnabled="False"" for Grids,but I didn't found any resources on the net
I have used "IsHitTestVisible="False"" property but it's not the result what I want,
so any help please,to achieve what I want
thanks for Help

Comment: Not sure I am completely following what you are trying to do.  I think it might be easiest if you make the grids be disabled by default and use a visual state to enable the grids when you hover over it.  Not sure if this will work very well on a touch screen   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I have used to create a hidden disabled grids that will show when I hover on the specific Grid

Comment: I will try your solution Sir :)

Comment: I have tried the [PointerEntered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerentered) event but when you disable all elements in the grid, this event doesn't fire